# prompt never returns on speech_recognition package in python interpreter session

Tags: python, terminal, speech-recognition, spyder, google-speech-api

I'm trying to code a 'Siri' type application, and the first step is to get the speech_recognition module to work. (I'm coding on a Mac). I opened terminal and got $ python -m speech_recognition to listen to, interpret, and transcribe my speech properly. But when I enter this series of code in an interpreter session:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
mic = sr.Microphone()
with mic as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    audio = r.listen(source)
```

the prompt never returns and my speech is not interpreted. My coded program (in Spyder) also isn't working and I'm assuming it's because of this. How can I fix this? I'm working with python 3.7. Also not sure if this matters but I'm 17 and I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: You need to write the code in a file, not in the interpreter session. As for never returns - it listens. Probably your audio is silent like microphone is muted.

Comment: I was using this https://realpython.com/python-speech-recognition/#working-with-microphones and my mic is on